# android app not available on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Publishing an App on Google Play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809682/publishing-an-app-on-google-play)

Like two hours ago i uploaded and published my android application. But my application isnt available on Google Play. Im really worried because i cant find it using direct link with my app package name. (https://market.android.com/details?id=com.xxx.xxx)
My package name begins with "com.", is that fine  ?

Im searching my app from pc btw. On my dev page i see my app is available for 1600+ devices.
My apk file is "active" and all other required fields im filled(like pic and description).

Comment: Yes, "com." is fine, and recommended. I've seen apps take 15 mins to get uploaded, I've seen it take up to 27 hours. Just be patient. At least you don't have to go through Apple's goon squad.

Comment: its magic. i was able to search for my app using direct link just 10mins after posting here...

Answer (score 1):

It can take more than a couple days for the app to be found by all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing to worry.
 Try.

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxx.xxx
```

You need a couple of hours for it to show. I remember mine took 5hours. Some other apps could take days.